# MFC RibbonBar -- programmatically minimize?

Tags: mfc, ribbon

The MFC ribbon bar has a menu item labelled 'Minimize the ribbon'.  When you select it, only the headers of each category are shown, and the ribbon pops up when the headers are clicked.  I'd like to programmatically force a ribbon into this state. Unfortunately, the only method I can find is `ToggleMimimizeState()` [sic], which will either put it into this state or take it out depending on its current state.

Looking at the MFC source code, the way the menu command works is through this code:

```
case idMinimize:
    if (m_pActiveCategory != NULL)
    {
        ASSERT_VALID(m_pActiveCategory);
        m_pActiveCategory->ShowElements(FALSE);
        RedrawWindow();
    }
```

`m_pActiveCategory` can be obtained from outside of the `CMFCRibbonBar` class through the `GetActiveCategory()` method, but unfortunately the category's `ShowElements()` method is `protected` and I cannot see a way of achieving the same effect with the public methods.

Neither does there seem to be an obvious way of determining whether the ribbon is currently minimized.

Is there something I'm missing, or do I just have to guess at the current state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derive two new classes from **CMFCRibbonBar** and **CMFCRibbonCategory**

```
class MyCMFCRibbonCategory: public CMFCRibbonCategory
{
public:
    void force_ShowElements(BOOL todo)
    {
        ShowElements(todo);
    }
};

class MyRibbonBar: public CMFCRibbonBar
{
public:
    BOOL is_minimized()
    {
        return m_dwHideFlags == AFX_RIBBONBAR_HIDE_ELEMENTS;
    }

    void minimize_me(BOOL show_minimized)
    {
        MyCMFCRibbonCategory* cc = (MyCMFCRibbonCategory*)GetActiveCategory();
        if (cc != NULL)
        {
            cc->force_ShowElements(!show_minimized);
            RedrawWindow();
        }
    }
};
```

then change in your CMainframe from

```
CMFCRibbonBar   m_wndRibbonBar;
```

to

```
MyRibbonBar     m_wndRibbonBar;
```

Now in your code you can use the new two members:

```
BOOL MyRibbonBar::is_minimized()
void MyRibbonBar::minimize_me(BOOL show_minimized)
```

Basic example:

```
void CMainFrame::OnButton2()
{
    if( m_wndRibbonBar.is_minimized() )
        m_wndRibbonBar.minimize_me(FALSE);
    else
        m_wndRibbonBar.minimize_me(TRUE);
}
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: Unacceptable! GetActiveCategory() does not actually point to a subobject of an object of type MyCMFCRibbonCategory. The cast causes undefined behaviour (see C++ standard 5.2.9).

Comment: Well, the standard way requires that an instance of MyCMFCRibbonCategory (or a class derived from it) must be created before downcasting to it. However, I would recommend to avoid casting whenever possible and never use C style casts. In this case you can create an instance of MyCMFCRibbonCategory and call "CopyFrom" where you supply the active category as parameter. Then you can safely call "force_ShowElements".

Answer (score 1):

A combination of the above worked for me. That is, I wanted to use the Ribbon as a tabbed set of extra functions on a main menu. However, I didn't want the ribbon to have the ability to stay maximized. I only wanted the user to click, see a few actions and after that, disappear.

In short, prevent the ribbon from docking, or staying maximized. Whatever you want to call it. Click a tab, then and icon on the ribbon and disappear.

Instructions:

1. I derived my own CMyRibbon class by inheriting from CMFCRibbonBar. (Done using Class wizard and making an MFC class)
2. Create an event handler for WM_SIZE in our new CMyRibbon class (ClassWizard)

```
void CMyRibbon::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
    CMFCRibbonBar::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

    if (!(GetHideFlags() & AFX_RIBBONBAR_HIDE_ELEMENTS))
        ToggleMimimizeState();
}
```

3. In CMainFrm.h add this change: 
   **CMyRibbon   m_wndRibbonBar;**

Answer (score 0):

Use m_wndRibbonBar.ToggleMimimizeState();

Answer (score -1):

Simply check (m_wndRibbonBar.GetHideFlags() & AFX_RIBBONBAR_HIDE_ELEMENTS) value.